# Can't download tickers "Key errror date"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just starting using python and when I try running this code that's supposed to download the tickers a Key Error date appears.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import math
from  pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stock_prices= pd.DataFrame()

tickers= ['tsla', 'appl', 'msft', 'goog', '^IXIC']
    
for i in tickers:
    stock_prices[i]= wb.DataReader(i, data_source='yahoo', start= s, end= e)['Adj Close']
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including the _full_ error traceback in the body of your question so that we can better understand your issue

Comment: In your example, you have a `start` and `end` parameter where you're using the variables of `s` and `e`. These variables need to be set (presumably as dates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `APPL` by `AAPL`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import math
from  pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stock_prices= pd.DataFrame()

tickers= ['TSLA', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', '^IXIC']

s = dt.datetime(2022,9,1)
e = dt.datetime(2022,9,9)
    
for i in tickers:
    stock_prices[i]= wb.DataReader(i, data_source='yahoo', start= s, end= e)['Adj Close']

stock_prices
```

##### `>>> Output`

[image]